# Kiwi TCMS: location of tcms.conf file to link RobotFramework robot files to Kiwi TCMS test cases for test execution reporting in Kiwi TCMS

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I am new to Kiwi TCMS.
My Manager installed the Kiwi TCMS and assigned me to a Test group.
I have used Visual Studio Code to create my RobotFramework test files.
I would like to setup my RobotFramework tests to link to the test cases I created in Kiwi TCMS in order that I can execute the Robot tests cases (automated) and they link to the relevant test case in Kiwi TCMS and a report can be done on test execution etc.
I have installed the Kiwi TCMS RobotFramework plugin in the Visual Studio Code.
With regard to the tcms.conf file - is this a file that should already be present and in the home directory e.g. C:\Users\username- and if so, would this be available to myself as a Test group user or would my Manager only have access (as he setup/installed Kiwi TCMS)

Answer (score 0):

I read the documentation. And I already appear to have the tcms-api installed on my home directory\appdata\local\progams\python\python39\lib\site-packages. With the .tcms.conf file do I create this within an editor like Notepad++ or some other editor as I am using Visual Studio Code, and place on my home directory or is it something I generate in the command prompt ?? Apologies I am new to Kiwi-TCMS and this kind of thing. – TinaTest Mar 3 at 10:52
Are you able to assist with this query, please? As I need to try and get this working asap. Many Thanks. –